# Auto Number by Grouping Column in Oracle

Tags: oracle, autonumber

Is there any oracle statement for my problem.

Eg. TableA has 2 columns : `columnA and columnB`

```
ColumnA    ColumnB
-------------------
 A         WA
 A         WA
 B         WA
 B         WA
 C         WA
 A         CA
 A         CA
 B         CA
 B         CA
 C         CA
```

What I want is : AutoNumber `Group by ColumnA`

```
Auto  ColumnA  ColumnB
-----------------------
1     A        WA
2     A        WA
3     A        CA
4     A        CA
1     B        WA
2     B        WA
3     B        CA
4     B        CA
1     C        WA
2     C        CA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ROW_NUMBER](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions156.htm#i86310) function for this. Group by your columnA and specify some order by clause.

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY columnA ORDER BY columnB) as "auto",
       columnA, columnB
  FROM table;
```